# Linux Shell: Copy output into clipboard w/o using the Mouse?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Is it possible to copy the output into the clipboard without using the mouse?

For example, I would like to do something like this:

$ pwd >> clipboard

Comment: cat /etc/passwd | xsel --clipboard

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can get and use the `xclip` and `xsel` commands. Instructions for obtaining and using them are [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/xclip-linux-insert-files-command-output-intoclipboard/).

Without any arguments, `xclip` copies into the primary (middle-click-paste) clipboard instead of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>/right-click-context-menu clipboard.

Try `echo foo | xclip -selection clipboard` to copy some text into the latter.

To output the clipboard to standard out: `xclip -selection clipboard -o`

The equivalent utility for MacOS is `pbcopy` (and `pbpaste`)

Comment: xclip doesn't work here.

Comment: @brauliobo: Where's "here"? Seriously, what do you mean? It doesn't work in what way, exactly?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I've tried `cat file | xclip` and it doesn't work

Comment: @brauliobo: It doesn't work in what way, *exactly*? Error message? Misbehavior? Magnetic field anomalies?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson it just don't copy, and I check that on `klipper`

Comment: @brauliobo: I presume `klipper` is a clipboard viewer. Try `cat file | xclip -selection clipboard` Without the extra arguments, `xclip` copies into the primary (middle-click-paste) clipboard instead of the Ctrl-C/Ctrl-V/right-click-context-menu clipboard.

Comment: @Dennis, maybe you can add the last comment to the answer as this is rather important and not obvious and a great addition.

Comment: @Kvothe: You're right. Done.

Answer (score 7):

If you are on a MAC you can use [pbcopy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pbcopy.1.html) like this:

```
pbcopy < thing_to_write_to_clipboard
```

Comment: Or  `your_command | pbcopy`, won't output anything but will copy the result into the clipboard.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid there is no such thing as "clipboard" in most linux shells, at least none I know of. There's a clipboard in the X server (if your system has X11, you may access it using `xclip` command). If you connect to your shell account using some ssh/terminal emulator software, like PuTTy, you can use the clipboard of the system you are using, but that still would be an external clipboard and you might not be able to avoid using mouse.

What I have found is this little neat bash script, found at
http://geek.phatus.com/2010/01/create-a-simple-yet-very-useful-bash-clipboard/ . It basically creates a temporary file which serves as a clipboard - you can clear, execute, write etc. your temporary data using a set of commands, which is actually what a clipboard does ;)

Comment: the op was just a little bit unclear about his setup: he meant the clipboard of the xserver.

Answer (score 3):

on Wayland xcopy doesn't seem to work, use [wl-clipboard](https://github.com/bugaevc/wl-clipboard) instead.
e.g. on fedora

```
sudo dnf install wl-clipboard

tree | wl-copy

wl-paste > file
```

Answer (score 2):

The bash variable $PWD contains the path directory of your terminal window. you might only want to pipe the command pwd into the clipboard so:

```
echo $PWD | pbcopy
```

also:
you can pipe the output of a command to a file.

like `pwd > file.txt`

so if you save a variable to your bash file you can :

```ps
pwd > $variable

cat $variable |pbcopy
```

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! How is this better than the other answers?

Comment: I don't have xclip.

Comment: But that works only under macOS/Darwin.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers above I would add that MSYS2 and Cygwin have neither `xclip` nor `xsel` by default, but implement `/dev/clipboard`:

```bash
$ pwd >> /dev/clipboard
```

Answer (score 0):

And an ugly way, for cases when you want to copy terminal output to clipboard but don't have a mouse connected to your machine — using "mouse keys" feature of X.

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>NumLock</kbd>, and your numpad keys will work to control cursor movement. You can then press <kbd>Num 0</kbd> to simulate press & hold LMB, and move the cursor as you need, then press <kbd>Num 5</kbd> to simulate release of LMB. Now you've selected your text. To simulate RMB you press <kbd>Num -</kbd> to change active mouse button, then <kbd>Num 5</kbd> to get context menu. Now you want to return to LMB mode: press <kbd>Num /</kbd>. Now you can move your cursor to "Copy" menu entry and press <kbd>Num 5</kbd>. That's all. You have your text in clipboard. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>NumLock</kbd> to get your numpad to its original function.

PS: In some distros (e.g. Kubuntu) mouse keys shortcut appears to be disabled by default or somehow hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I made a small tool providing similar functionality, without using xclip or xsel. Std out is copied to a clipboard and can be pasted again in the terminal, see:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/commandlinecopypaste/

Note, that this tool does not need an x-session. The clipboard can just be used within terminal and not be pasted by ctrl+v or middle-mouse-click into other x-windows

Comment: Really — your code is not using 'the clipboard' _per se_, but rather just copying the contents from the stdin to a file, and reading from it.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the shell within a **screen** or **byobu** session, you can do this:

1. Enter scrollback mode: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>F7</kbd> in **byobu**.
2. Move the cursor to the start of the text you want to copy, hit <kbd>space</kbd>.
3. Move the cursor to the end of the text you want to copy and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. To paste text, hit  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>]</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd>.

So you can copy not only a command output, but any part of the terminal window.